# Instantiation of generic lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

The following does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class F, class G>
auto static_if (std::true_type, F && f, G && g) {
    return std::forward<F> (f) (0);
}   

template <class F, class G>
auto static_if (std::false_type, F && f, G && g) {
    return std::forward<G> (g) (0);
}


template <class T> std::true_type constexpr is_pointer (T *) { return {}; }
template <class T> std::false_type constexpr is_pointer (T) { return {}; }

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    static_if (
        is_pointer (x),
        [&] (auto) { std::cout << *x << std::endl; },
        [&] (auto) { std::cout << "no pointer" << std::endl; }
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with the error message:

```
prog.cpp: In lambda function:
prog.cpp:23:33: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
      [&] (auto) { std::cout << *x << std::endl; },
```

See here: http://ideone.com/frl8rn

Now the question is: Why?

It is clear that compilation should fail if the lambdas were not generic (no `auto` parameter).

Yet we have two *generic* lambdas here. Each of them should only be instantiated when it is used (which means: *called*, or, at least, when its `operator ()` is somehow referenced).

The generic lambda generating the error message should therefore *not* be instantiated, since the second overload of `static_if` is used, in the definition of which the parameter `f` is *not* called. Since the generic lambda's `operator ()` is not used, the compiler should simply ignore it.

Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: C++17 may help with `if constexpr`.

Comment: Hm, now I read this: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html Wouldn't the exact same problem arise with `constexpr if`, without the possibility of solving it by delaying the type check, as, e.g., described in my comment to Jarod42's answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is a non template dependent type, so the check is done in first pass of template checking, as `static_assert(false, "")` fires even for non instantiated template.

Comment: Hence writing `[&] (auto dummy) { std::cout << *(dummy, x) << std::endl; }` solves the problem. See here: http://ideone.com/1yiLYo Thank you very much for your most helpful response. Is there a better solution than mine?

Answer (score 4):

In the comment to the accepted answer, you ask if there's a better solution. Arguably below is one (live code [here](http://ideone.com/frGsrA)). Instead of capturing x locally, you generalise your `static_if` to generically forward any arguments to either of the two lambdas, and make your `x` such an argument. Then you don't need the dance with dummy variables you have in the comment.

```
template <class F, class G, class ... Args>
auto static_if (std::true_type, F && f, G && g, Args && ... args) {
    return std::forward<F> (f) (std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}   

template <class F, class G, class ... Args>
auto static_if (std::false_type, F && f, G && g, Args && ... args) {
    return std::forward<G> (g) (std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


template <class T> std::true_type constexpr is_pointer (T *) { return {}; }
template <class T> std::false_type constexpr is_pointer (T) { return {}; }

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    static_if (
        is_pointer (x),
        [] (auto x) { std::cout << *x << std::endl; },
        [] (auto x) { std::cout << "no pointer" << std::endl; },
        x
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I sort of like grouping the 3 kinds of parameters somehow (the condition, the lambda branches, and the arguments to thr lambdas).  Also, the above requires an awkward wrapping if we want to use a `constexpr bool` and not `std::true_type` branching.

Answer (score 1):

`[&x](auto){ std::cout<<*x<<'\n'; }` is a lambda with a template `operator()`.  Template `operator()`s that have no possible type passed to them that make them compile are not legal in C++.

The validity of `*x` does not change based on the template argument.

A good way around this is to change how your `static_if` works.

```
template <class F, class G>
auto static_branch (std::true_type, F && f, G && g) {
  return std::forward<F>(f);
}
template <class F, class G>
auto static_branch (std::false_type, F && f, G && g) {
  return std::forward<G>(g);
}
template <bool test, class F, class G>
auto static_branch(F && f, G && g) {
  return static_branch( std::integral_constant<bool, test>{}, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<G>(g) );
}
```

notice we don't invoke the `f` or `g`.  Instead we return one or the other.

```
int main() {
  int x = 5;
  auto branch = static_branch (
    is_pointer (x),
    [&] (auto&&x) { std::cout << *x << std::endl; },
    [&] (auto&&) { std::cout << "no pointer" << std::endl; }
  );
  branch(x);
  return 0;
}
```

now the `x` is *passed into* the appropriate lambda.  Which means only when `x` is a pointer is the `*x` code evaluated.

```
  int* px = &x;
  static_branch (
    is_pointer(y),
    [&] (auto&&x) { std::cout << *x << std::endl; },
    [&] (auto&&) { std::cout << "no pointer" << std::endl; }
  )(y);
```

would then invoke the first branch.

You could also wait for C++17, where `constexpr if` may solve your problem; I am uncertain.